# How to rotate object with offset by orbit control in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to control object like this:
[image: helpful diagram]

Now camera is move around Y coordinate, but need to be move around NEW Y. Code is here:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
cube.position.x = 300;
// controls.target = THREE.Vector3(300, 0, 0);
```

I found that target option can set the focus point of the controls, but if I add this code: `controls.target = THREE.Vector3(300, 0, 0);` the object back to the center of the screen, but it should be at the right edge.

More over, when I set `new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);` to `new THREE.OrbitControls(cube);` and add `controls.target = THREE.Vector3(300, 0, 0);` control doesn't work, but when I set `controls.target = THREE.Vector3(301, 0, 0);` it is managed but not like a camera

Comment: OrbitControls is made to Orbit around an object, judging by your image, you want to rotate the object. Maybe [another one of the controls (in the examples folder)](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/js/controls) is what you want

Comment: Have you solved it? I face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

[OrbitControls.target](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/controls/OrbitControls.target) set the focus point of the controls and the `.object` orbits around this. But it is a manually manipulation. As mentioned in the documentation [OrbitControls.update()](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/controls/OrbitControls.update) must be called after any manual changes to the camera's transform.

e.g.

```
controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0)
controls.update();
```

See the example:

```js
(function onLoad() {
  var container, camera, scene, renderer, controls;
  
  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true
    });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100);
    camera.position.set(0, 1.0, -4);
    
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    scene.add(camera);
    window.onresize = resize;
    
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.5 );
    directionalLight.position.set(1,2,1.5);
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, container);
    controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(3, 0, 0)
    controls.update();
    controls.autoRotate = true;
    controls.autoRotateSpeed = 5.0
            
    var axis = new THREE.AxesHelper(1000);
    scene.add(axis);

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'#b090b0'});
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    scene.add(mesh);
  }


  function resize() {   
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```